# Can Not change the color of Notification LED on HTC Phone

Tags: android, android-notifications

For my activity I am creating, I want to be able to change the color of the LED (The same LED that tells Charging Status) to Solid RED when a method is called and Solid Green when another method is called.  So far nothing I have tried has worked.  Maybe this is not even possible on HTC phones.  I am using an HTC Desire 626.  I tried my functions with both the device plugged in and not plugged into the USB.  Nothing seems to change this notification at all.  I do not see any special permissions I need to include and I get no exceptions in the LogCat.

I will include my methods to change the LEDs, please help!

```
private void notification_RED(){
    AccelerometerResult.setText("The Indicator light should now be Red");
    AccelerometerResult.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    String ns = getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification = new Notification();
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
    notification.defaults = 0;
    notification.ledARGB = 0xff0000ff;
    //notification.ledARGB = Color.RED;
    notification.priority = Notification.PRIORITY_MAX;
    notification.ledOnMS = 1000;
    notification.ledOffMS = 300;
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
}

private void notification_GREEN(){
    AccelerometerResult.setText("The Indicator light should now be GREEN");
    AccelerometerResult.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

    String ns = getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification = new Notification();
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
    notification.ledARGB = Color.GREEN;
    notification.priority = Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT;
    notification.ledOnMS = 1000;
    notification.ledOffMS = 300;

    mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);

}
```

Comment: How are you planning on forcing device manufacturers to add in the LEDs that you seek? You are *asking* for certain LED colors. Do not assume that the device even has an LED that you can control, let alone control the color.

Comment: I know there is a green and a red for the models I am testing, so that is why I was testing those colors.

Comment: The manufacturer does not need to allow developers to control the color, though. The manufacturer is welcome to do whatever it wants, such as reserve the red color for a low-battery state.

Answer (score 1):

This light can only be changed when the phone is locked. That's why it's called a notification light. To notify about something while the screen is on use a toast, a popup or a notification.